# HERE SDK for Flutter: exit information in maneuvers

Tags: here-api

Is there a way with HERE SDK for Flutter to get information about the motorway exit?
I read the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/dev_guide/topics/navigation.html) but I can't find anything.

I would like to show the name of the next motorway exit the driver should follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For navigation you register at the RouteProgressListener (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/navigation/RouteProgressListener-class.html) for progress updates.

In this callback (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/navigation/RouteProgressListener/onRouteProgressUpdated.html) your get the route progress object (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/navigation/RouteProgress/RouteProgress.html).

With this you know the index for the next maneuver and you query the Navigator for the concrete maneuver object via getManeuver (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/navigation/NavigatorInterface/getManeuver.html)

In this maneuver object (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/routing/Maneuver-class.html) you can get the exist sign text (https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/api_reference/routing/Maneuver/exitSignTexts.html) if available (in most cases only for highways of course).